# R converting POSIXct dates with BST/GMT tags using as.Date()

Tags: r, date, xts, binary-search-tree, posixct

I need to use as.Date on the index of a zoo object. Some of the dates are in BST and so when converting I lose a day on (only) these entries. I don't care about one hour's difference or even the time part of the date at all, I just want to make sure that the dates displayed stay the same. I'm guessing this is not very hard but I can't manage it. Can somebody help please?

```
class(xtsRet)
#[1] "xts" "zoo"

index(xtsRet)
#[1] "2007-07-31 BST" "2007-08-31 BST" "2007-09-30 BST" "2007-10-31 GMT"

class(index(xtsRet))
#[1] "POSIXt"  "POSIXct"

index(xtsRet) <- as.Date(index(xtsRet))

index(xtsRet)
#[1] "2007-07-30" "2007-08-30" "2007-09-29" "2007-10-31"
```

Minimally reproducible example (not requiring `zoo` package):

```
my_date <- as.POSIXct("2007-04-01") # Users in non-UK timezone will need to
                                    # do as.POSIXct("2007-04-01", "Europe/London")
my_date
#[1] "2017-04-01 BST"

as.Date(my_date)
#[1] "2017-03-31"
```

Comment: It's easier to answer if you provide a reproducible example.  At a guess, does converting to `character` before you convert to `Date` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can offset the `POSIX` objects so its not based around midnight. 1 hour (3600 secs) should be sufficient:

```
d <- as.POSIXct(c("2007-07-31","2007-08-31","2007-09-30","2007-10-31"))
d
[1] "2007-07-31 BST" "2007-08-31 BST" "2007-09-30 BST" "2007-10-31 GMT"

as.Date(d)
[1] "2007-07-30" "2007-08-30" "2007-09-29" "2007-10-31"
as.Date(d+3600)
[1] "2007-07-31" "2007-08-31" "2007-09-30" "2007-10-31"
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer did exactly what I wanted but unfortunately for me the program I was using in does not seem to like this later down the line. Anyway, good post, I have accepted - thanks again.

Comment: @SWilliams What do you mean by "does not like it later down the line"? `d+3600` creates a temporary, so shouldn't have affected any other part of your program.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have this sample data:

```
library(zoo)
x <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01", tz = "GMT")
```

Then see if any of these are what you want:

```
# use current time zone
as.Date(as.character(x, tz = ""))

# use GMT
as.Date(as.character(x, tz = "GMT"))

# set entire session to GMT
Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")
as.Date(x)
```

Also try `"BST"` in place of `"GMT"` and note the article on dates and times in [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) .

Comment: Note the problem comes down to `as.POSIXct` having a default value for `tz` of `""` which indicates current timezone, while `as.Date.POSIXct` has a default value of `"UTC"` for `tz`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using as.POSIXlt to convert to a date object, wrapped in as.Date:

```
d <- as.POSIXct(c("2007-07-31","2007-08-31","2007-09-30","2007-10-31"))

d
[1] "2007-07-31 BST" "2007-08-31 BST" "2007-09-30 BST" "2007-10-31 GMT"

as.Date(as.POSIXlt(d))
[1] "2007-07-31" "2007-08-31" "2007-09-30" "2007-10-31"
```

Achieves the same thing as the +3600 above, but slightly less of a hack